# Allowing includegraphics in LaTeX to include files with arbitrary filenames

Tags: latex

I have some graphic files with some rather long filenames which includes several periods. `includegraphics` interprets the first of these as the beginning of the file extension, which makes it impossible for it to guess the proper graphics extension. A typical error message is

```
LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .9332.1dwc_kpl_h.log.png
```

One solution is to rename all files, but they are generated by another program, and I would rather use the naming scheme from there. Is there a way to tell `graphics` what the image format is, such that the extension will be ignored?

Comment: If you put the full name, with extension, does it still not work?

Comment: Actually, the compiler chokes if you have more than one period *anywhere* in the file name. It considers the extension the occurrence of the first period on.

Comment: You may want to try asking this question on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 24):

You can also hide the dots from LaTeX by putting extra curly braces in:

```
\includegraphics{{my.file.with.dots.in.it}.png}
```

(from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10574/includegraphics-dots-in-filename)

Comment: Works perfect! (why isn't this answer considered a "good" answer?)

Comment: Excellent ! it solved my problems while trying to pass `ext=.pdf` using the [`xkeyval`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval) LaTeX package, and then assemble the filename with its extension programmatically in LaTeX.@Thomas: shouldn't this be the accepted answer ?

Answer (score 7):

Use the [grffile](http://ctan.org/pkg/grffile) package.